# When the image of a homomorphism of Lie Algebras is an ideal?

Tags: ideals, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}_{1}$, $\mathfrak{g}_{2}$ be Lie algebras and

$$ \varphi : \mathfrak{g}_{1} \rightarrow \mathfrak{g}_{2} $$

be a homomorphism of Lie algebras. Somebody could tell me (proof) a necessary and 
sufficient condition on $\varphi$ to ensure that $\mbox{Im}\varphi$ be an 
ideal of $\mathfrak{g}_{2}$?

I would be happy with any suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: You can't expect any nontrivial answer. For you include the case when $\varphi$ is the inclusion of a subalgebra. So your question is actually equivalent to: give a necessary and sufficient condition for a subalgebra to be an ideal. Well, it's an ideal iff it's an ideal. Apart from specific contexts, you don't expect to say further.

Comment: $\mbox{Im}  \ \varphi$ is trivialy always an ideal.

Comment: @marshalcraft No, this is not true. Take $\mathbb{g}_2$ to be simple, and find a counterexample!

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to give a sufficient condition, mamely that $\phi$ is surjective. In this case, $\phi(I)$ is an ideal in $\mathfrak{g}_2$ for any ideal $I$ in $\mathfrak{g}_1$, because
$$
[\mathfrak{g}_2,\phi(I)]=[\phi(\mathfrak{g}_1),\phi(I)]=\phi([\mathfrak{g}_1,I])\subseteq \phi(I).
$$

However, this is not a necessary condition. For, say, $\phi=0$ and $\mathfrak{g}_2\neq 0$, we have that $\phi(I)$ is an ideal, although $\phi$ is not surjective.

Comment: If $\varphi $ is surjective then $\mathfrak g_2$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak g_1 /kern(\varphi)$. Also $kern(\varphi)$ is an ideal in $\mathfrak g_1$. In general by the isomorphism theorems.

Comment: Yes, but this is independent of the answer, right? So if $\phi=0$ is surjective, then $\mathfrak{g}_2\cong \mathfrak{g}_1/\mathfrak{g}_1=0$.